# How to hide all but only selected elements under parent element using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have an HTML structure like the following

```html
<div class="fieldset-wrapper">
  <div data-index="one">...</div>
  <div data-index="two">...</div>
  <div data-index="three">...</div>
  <div data-index="four">...</div>
</div>
```

I want to keep only the div elements with 'data-index' attribute values 'one' & 'three'.
I have tried the following, but it is not working.

```js
$('.fieldset-wrapper div:not([data-index="one"]):not([data-index="three"])').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="fieldset-wrapper">
  <div data-index="one">one</div>
  <div data-index="two">two</div>
  <div data-index="three">three</div>
  <div data-index="four">four</div>
</div>
```

How should I do this?

Comment: Your code looks like you want to hide anything BUT one and three

Comment: BTW, your code works fine. What does *"not working"* mean here?

Comment: *"I want to hide only the div elements with 'data-index' attribute value 'one' & 'three'."*: yet in your code you instruct to **not** hide these, but all others. Please clarify.

Comment: I updated your question, with the code turned into a runnable snippet. If you run it, it does exactly as you seem to want: all except those two are hidden. Please clarify what the problem is.

Comment: @trincot Thanks for this. The same code snippet is somehow not working on my end. The problem might be elsewhere.

Comment: One of the reasons could be that your document has not yet (completely) loaded when this code is executed, and so the `$()` selector finds nothing to hide. But we can only guess... And if the elements are not yet in the document, the answers posted below will not do the job either.

Comment: Can you also fix the title "*all but only*" makes no sense.   Could be "all except" (most likely) or "all but not" (same as "all except") or "all" (unlikely) or "only" (seems the opposite)

Comment: Note: the snippet editor runs the code with the javascript *at the bottom*, after the HTML.   Try moving your code to the bottom.  If that works, that's the issue and solution is to move it the bottom or wrap in doc.ready, eg:  `$(function() { $('.fieldset-wrapper div... });`

Comment: Have you checked that the document is loaded? What does `$('.fieldset-wrapper div[data-index]').length` give you?

Comment: @trincot You were right. The elements inside the `.fieldset-wrapper` class was being loaded using Knockout Js, and was loading after my Js was being executed. So during my code execution, the element doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine, but the HTML elements that you target should be there at the moment your JavaScript (jQuery) code executes. This is apparently not the case, as otherwise elements would have been hidden successfully.

If the HTML elements are loaded at page load, then await the page to be loaded, like so:

```
$(function () {
    $('.fieldset-wrapper div:not([data-index="one"]):not([data-index="three"])').hide();
}
```

Or if the content is loaded by a separate fetch (ajax), then execute this operation only when that HTML has been inserted. For instance, if that dynamic HTML loading is done with jQuery's `.load()` then it would like like this:

```
$( ".fieldset-wrapper" ).load("ajax/some_dynamic_content.html", function() {
    $('.fieldset-wrapper div:not([data-index="one"]):not([data-index="three"])').hide();
});
```

...but many other patterns exist to load content dynamically. In any case, you need to execute the relevant code when you are notified that the content has been loaded.

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE:** You of course have to run the code after the elements are available

In the codes below I added the container as context to be more specific

*I want to ***HIDE*** only the div elements with 'data-index' attribute value 'one' & 'three'*

```js
$("div[data-index=one],div[data-index=three]",".fieldset-wrapper").hide()
```

```css
div.fieldset-wrapper { background-color: yellow }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fieldset-wrapper">
  <div data-index="one">One</div>
  <div data-index="two">Two</div>
  <div data-index="three">Three</div>
  <div data-index="four">Four</div>
</div>
<hr/>

<div class="NOTfieldset-wrapper">
  <div data-index="one">One</div>
  <div data-index="two">Two</div>
  <div data-index="three">Three</div>
  <div data-index="four">Four</div>
</div>
```

*I want to ***SHOW*** only the div elements with 'data-index' attribute value 'one' & 'three'*

```js
const indicesToShow = ["one", "three"];
$(".fieldset-wrapper > div").hide();
const selector = indicesToShow.map(index => `> div[data-index='${index}']`).join(",");
$(selector,".fieldset-wrapper").show();
```

```css
div.fieldset-wrapper { background-color: yellow }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fieldset-wrapper">
  <div data-index="one">One</div>
  <div data-index="two">Two</div>
  <div data-index="three">Three</div>
  <div data-index="four">Four</div>
</div>

<div class="NOTfieldset-wrapper">
  <div data-index="one">One</div>
  <div data-index="two">Two</div>
  <div data-index="three">Three</div>
  <div data-index="four">Four</div>
</div>
```

Comment: this solution will hide all the div which has data-index=one || two, it should only hide all under `fieldset-wrapper` div :). And I don't thing there is issue using filter.

Comment: That is where you are wrong. I have set the CONTEXT to the field-wrapper $("div[data-index=one],div[data-index=three]",`".fieldset-wrapper"`)

Comment: "*I don't thing there is issue using filter*" - Unsure how this is related? This answer is just demonstrating another approach and is not condemning the use of `filter`?

Comment: Using filter can be useful. Here it is just unnecessarily complex, especially with `:not` in parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `filter` method.

First, select all the div then filter the divs which you want to hide then call the hide method

```js
$('.fieldset-wrapper div').filter(':not([data-index="one"], [data-index="three"])').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fieldset-wrapper">
  <div data-index="one">1...</div>
  <div data-index="two">2...</div>
  <div data-index="three">3...</div>
  <div data-index="four">4...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `$(".wrapper div").filter(".x")` is just different syntax for / the same as `$(".wrapper div.x")`